# permissionBlocker class on <div> disables scrolling on IE

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, internet-explorer

### AngularJS ng-disable on div disables scrolling on IE

I have a potentially long list of letters that I would like to make scrollable. However, when a user only has view permissions, the div is set to disabled so they can't make any changes. On Chrome this works fine, but on IE (v11.0.120) the the scrollbar is disabled so the user can't see anything other than the first few items.

The disabled tag is added through a directive based on user credentials. If the user doesn't even have view permissions ng-show is set to false and the directive doesn't appear at all.

The first solution I tried was trying to override the child status by adding `ng-disabled=false`, but this does nothing.

The second solution (which technically works) was switching the order of the elements so that the scrolling div is outside of the permission blocker. The problem with this is that if users without permissions will still be able to see the wrapper element that has the data on it if they are smart enough to open developer tools. While they shouldn't ever be able to navigate to the page in the first place, I'd rather find a different solution.

Here is a (very) simplified version of the layout and a link to the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tjkind/9epcdoxL/15/).

```html
<div ng-app ng-controller="EmpCtrl">
    <div class="title">Employee Information</div>
    <div>{{employee.firstName}} {{employee.lastName}}</div>
    <div class="permissionBlocker" ng-disabled='true'>
    <div class="wrapper" data-employee-number="employee.Id">
      <div id="container">
        <ul>
          <li>Letter 1</li>
          <li>Letter 2</li>
          <li>Letter 3</li>
          <li>Letter 4</li>
          <li>Letter 5</li>
          <li>Letter 6</li>
          <li>Letter 7</li>
          <li>Letter 8</li>
          <li>Letter 9</li>
          <li>Letter 10</li>
          <li>Letter 11</li>
          <li>Letter 12</li>
          <li>Letter 13</li>
          <li>Letter 14</li>
          <li>Letter 15</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The `disabled` attribute is a mixin for `<button>`, `<command>`, `<fieldset>`, `<input>`, `<keygen>`, `<optgroup>`, `<option>`, `<select>`, `<textarea>`. It is not an attribute for `<div>` elements. The `.permissionBlocker` class CSS is doing something other than setting the disabled attribute.

Comment: @georgeawg in the jsfiddle I linked there is nothing else being done to the permissionBlocker class, and yet the scroll is still disabled when run in IE. Plus, when I remove the disabled attribute the scroll works. Is there something else that I'm missing?

Comment: Can you show us the code for the directive that adds the disabled "tag"? "Tag" is the wrong word. I would like to see what it is really doing.

Comment: Unfortunately, it relates a little to closely to how authentication is done for me to feel comfortable sharing. I'm still a little confused on why it matters. As I've shown above, all it takes is adding the disabled "tag".

Comment: `<div>` doesn't have the attribute `ng-disabled` and I think it's the cause of the issue. What are the elements you want to disable in the `<div>`? I can't see it in your example code. I think you should disable themselves instead of the whole `<div>`. If there're some `<input>` or `<textarea>`, you can use `ng-readonly` to make them readonly.